# JQuery: How to refresh event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery handler bound to a DOM element.

```
  $('.details-control').click( function () {
      var tr = $(this).closest('tr.parentRow');
      var row = table.row(tr);
      var nestedTable = tr.children('td.nested').children('table.nested').clone(true);


        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(nestedTable).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
  });
```

The above element is in a paginated table, so when the table gets paginated the ('.details-control') elements on the page change and these do not have the event attached.

I would like to have the events attached to these new $('details-control') elements.

The only way I can think of is to rewrite the code again like below...

```
  $('.pagination').click( function () {
  //copy-paste $('.details-control').click( function () {....

  });
```

But I think there must be a better way.. but nothing comes up in my searches because I'm not sure what search terms this even falls under.

Is there a way I can name the details-control event and call it or  so I don't have to copy-paste or a way to reattach or refresh the handlers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for event delegation which is the process of attaching the handler on a container and filtering events that bubble-up according to a specific criteria (a selector in this case). Assuming `.pagination` is the parent of `.details-control` and that parent never gets replaced:

```
$('.pagination').on('click', '.details-control', yourHandler);
```

Comment: `.pagination` is not the parent of `.details-control`. `details-control` is in my table and `.pagination` is not.

Comment: @Phil Well, just use event delegation on the closest parent of `.details-control` that will never get replaced.

Comment: I am just reading about it now, I think I can use the the table as the parent. Thanks!

Comment: @Phil As long as the entire table doesn't get replaced, yes that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use on handlers.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $( selector ).on('click', function () { 
        // logic 
     })
  })
```

You can turn these on and off dynamically with on() and off()